# How can I pull request if i have over 14k changes, is it normal that node_modules is so big?

Tags: node.js, git

[scr of my PR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKPC2.png)

Hello. I did PR from terminal to github as always but the file is so big that I cannot scroll down to get the final commit and pull request button. What do I do in this situation?

Is it normal that node_modules is so big or I have just installed some bad things?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that node_modules should be added/committed _ever_ given that it's stuff that is downloaded from dependencies.

Comment: I am new to this. So can i delete node_modules after I used webpack?

Comment: Usually you have /node_modules in your .gitignore so it does not show up in your diff.

Comment: When committing, no need to add the `node_modules` directory to GitHub. Create a new file called `.gitignore` and add the `node_modules/`  in that. You will notice a difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+node_modules

Comment: As said before, 'nodes_modules' should not be tracked so maybe repo owner need to ignore **and untrack it** before you will do your PR. Maybe you should open an issue to ask for that if it's the case. If the repo is public, could you share the url so it could be checked?